# How can i add an item in a tree object, when i first have to search the level where the item should be added?

Tags: typescript

I have a tree object:

```
interface Node {
  id:number;
  name:string;
  children?: Node[];
}


NODE_DATA: Node[]= [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'A'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'C',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'D',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'E',
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'F'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, i need a function that get an "id" of a Node as a parameter and add another Node,
for example {id: 7, name: 'G'},
to "children" of the Node with the given "id".

Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wkl1Jw) what you're looking for? Nothing prevents a tree from having multiple nodes with the same id, so I assume you want to add the new node to the first one encountered via some tree walk, and not *all* such nodes.  And I assume you want to modify the existing tree instead of copying.  Anyway if those work for you I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. But can I ask you about the line with the two question marks:
(node.children ??= []).push(newNode);
I have never seen something like this before. Is this a short form for something?

Comment: It's [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment).

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to write a function with call signature `declare function addChild(nodes: Node[], parentId: number, newNode: Node): void;` in which `newNode` is added to the `children` property of the node in the `nodes` tree with an `id` of `parentId`.  Assumptions:

- you want to *mutate* existing trees (instead of copying them)
- if, for some reason, multiple nodes exist in the tree with the target id, you are okay adding the new node to the children of just one of them (the first one you run into when you walk the tree).
- if, for some reason, *no* node in the tree has the target id, you are okay if the tree is not changed at all.

Here's one approach:

```
function addChild(nodes: Node[], parentId: number, newNode: Node): boolean {
  for (const node of nodes) {
    if (node.id === parentId) {
      (node.children ??= []).push(newNode);
      return true;
    }
    if (node.children) {
      const found = addChild(node.children, parentId, newNode);
      if (found) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is a recursive function, which is the most straightforward approach to dealing with recursive data structures.  I've made it return a `boolean` value which reports whether or not it has found the target node.  This makes it easy to short-circuit the tree walking and essentially exit once the node has been found.

For each `node` in the `nodes` array we check its `id`.  If it's the `parentId` then we've found the node (so we'll return `true`) and we can add `newNode` to its `children`.  Of course since `children` is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) we need to possibly initialize it to an empty array before adding `newNode`.  This could be done like

```
if (!node.children) { node.children = []; }
node.children.push(newNode);
```

but using [nullish coalescing assignment (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) it can be collapsed to the single line

```
(node.children ??= []).push(newNode);
```

That's because the assignment only happens if the left-hand side is `undefined` or `null`, and the expression evaluates to the (new) left-hand side, meaning it's known to be an array.

If the current node isn't the target node then we recursively apply `addChild` to its `children`.  If any of those recursive calls finds the target node, then it will return `true` and thus we can exit early.  Otherwise we keep going.

Finally, at the very end, if we haven't found the target node, we return `false`. This is hopefully not the case for the call made by the user, but it is expected to happen in many of the subtrees of the original tree.

---

Let's test it out:

```
addChild(NODE_DATA, 4, { id: 7, name: "G" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(NODE_DATA))
// "[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B","children":[{"id":3,"name":"C"},
//   {"id":4,"name":"D","children":[{"id":7,"name":"G"}]},
//   {"id":5,"name":"E","children":[{"id":6,"name":"F"}]}]}]"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=57&ssc=1&pln=62&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJICWwALhAE4BmCyAcgPYAmyBxJZrAXEsACuYAEY0A3EW4DwEflArVyAc0lcS8ABakMrahGAB+fi3YBtALpqSAXyJSk8ZsAVJGAeQAiAUQD6ngEEAFQCTNghLJABeJDMHEk5pElI+JABGABp47lBIfgByAPzsmyz1PGzk1IAmMqSZPKR8gCF8uqStHT0Dfjjy6UT67hT+AGZ2oYa5JoBhNsruUoWE5eHUgBYJodzp-M95-sWtgdWq-gBWY6Sdgu8DyY1tXX1gXtPuQYe1-gA2K8mbk0AGLFQ71Oxg7gWVYQ+rQ8qwpDwhy0QTAeAUUjOJAgVisGZPVgACmA4SgYXMFgySDgLwoAElUkJRDRqcAIAB3UzTbkASn4ImYzAwEBAwAq5VozGoSCJThcFAE4SQzFoSvYUF5EvqpDVJPCADoUtEojFaQYGawtZ8kqsAPR2sh6gCEpPYBs6zwMWrdEA9hJe0ViVntjt9-q6LwNMEEUE0JM5fLUq317s93XFhkMMUsvOjsfj7K54V51iG+gogmo4sUgggZekiOkutl4fTL2tq3lrilaNYQdx+MJqb97YM1PNlEZbMTJYbSRbRN7wCtSArVZr1Dr89sJWy6+rSHoGCg9YcEIcg4JXSJHh8-mCAWpmzwPH4AHY2bJ+AAiADiP5IDYpYON2wp+hgzDKESKAAMruIwBoKEowDKLqACet5eH4gQhLyvIOA6SA-mYuA-ikP68JkP47JRP4BD+pRkRRvC1DRsh0c0P4ZD+Y7AJRpHkawlHjOxkB0TMjHtERCRCZRmxiRAdGeNxvEBgYAnMcJvCfopdEATYFhLFwMl4HJvCXHpvA-t4ql8Zp5l-FZP5AoxRnuYB9iEBCQA)